# Lucene - search a subset with boolean query

Tags: lucene

I have an index with a field (eg. field1) with two rows, one is "short greg" and the second one is "great greg".
if I search with (using Luke) : field1:g*  field1:greg

the result will be both rows but with the same score!
These because both words have the same initial character G.

My expectation is "great greg" with the maximum score, where G* give more weight to the score of "GREAT GREG".

the question is : how to write this query ? 
thanks anyway

Comment: It is, [how do you think](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) you should do it?

Comment: thanks for the comment (and the useful link), I don't know if is possible to filter the result using the same initial character, so I put this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the identical score might be because your query is equivalent to:

`field1:g* OR field1:greg`

I would try in Luke:

`+field1:g* +field1:greg`

(which is equivalent to

`field1:g* AND field1:greg`

Comment: thank you for the comment, using AND operator don't change the score